# Is a Gigatexel equal to a billion chars, or a billion floats?

Tags: image-processing, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm looking at [NVIDIA's whitepaper on the GTX680 GPU](http://www.geforce.com/Active/en_US/en_US/pdf/GeForce-GTX-680-Whitepaper-FINAL.pdf). On page 6, the whitepaper mentions that GTX680 has a fill rate of 128.8 Gigatexels/sec.

I have a couple of questions about this:

1. Is one texel equal to *one byte*, or *four bytes*? In other words, is a texel an RGBA (or float), or just a char?
2. Is "**fill rate** of 128.8 Gigatexels/sec" the same thing as saying "**bandwidth** of 128.8 GB/s?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gigatexels is a measure of the texture unit throughput. Basically it is capable of 128.8 billion filtered texture samples per second.

1) A texel can vary in size as you mention. A texture is often RGBA 4 chars (4-bytes), float (4-bytes), or 4 floats (16-bytes). There are other texture formats and a texel refers to the data for one point on the texture.

2) No. The memory throughput in GB/s defines how fast the GPU can 'potentially' read from its main/global memory. If texture samples are not coherant (i.e. not using the same/neighbouring section of a texture) then a global fetch will be required and bandwith to main memory becomes a concern. This also applies to any data unlike the Gigatexel figure and also includes the fact that the vertex data is also read from memory. Having a high bandwidth is critical especially when there are many if not thousands of cores requesting these datas.